# applying more than one condition to different columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have  the following data frame:

```
id1 id2 qtty    cat output
15994   15994   30  1   1
25787   26275   7   2   1
122301  122301  0   0   0
36199   35333   14  2   1
36199   36199   15  1   1
46223   45746   14  2   1
46223   46223   15  1   1
80570   80570   0   0   0
55728   55728   1   1   1
94218   94218   0   0   0
69456   66837   5   2   1
```

where `cat` is the column that I want to generate according to the following criteria:

```
id1=id2 and qtty=0 then cat=0
id1=id2 and qtty>0 then cat=1
id1!=id2 and qtty=0 then cat=2
id1!=id2 and qtty>0 then cat=2
```

`output` is what I'm getting and what I did was:

```
  status<-function(dataframe){
  store<-rep(0,length(dataframe[,1]))
  for(i in 1: length(dataframe[,1])) {
    if(dataframe[i,1]==dataframe[i,2]) {
      if(dataframe[i,3]==0) {store[i]<-0}
        else
          if(dataframe[i,1]==dataframe[i,2]) {
            if(dataframe[i,3]>0) {store[i]<-1}
              else
                if(dataframe[i,1]!=dataframe[i,2]) {
                  if(dataframe[i,3]>0) {store[i]<-2}
                    else store[i]<-2
               }
            }
         }
     }
  return(store)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  Also, please go back over your previous questions and mark accepted answers by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Thanks, I already got an answer, which works. Cheers. (previous answer: accepted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done with `ifelse`: (assuming `dat` is your data frame)

```
within(dat, cat <- ifelse(id1 != id2, 2, qtty > 0))
```

The result:

```
      id1    id2 qtty cat output
1   15994  15994   30   1      1
2   25787  26275    7   2      1
3  122301 122301    0   0      0
4   36199  35333   14   2      1
5   36199  36199   15   1      1
6   46223  45746   14   2      1
7   46223  46223   15   1      1
8   80570  80570    0   0      0
9   55728  55728    1   1      1
10  94218  94218    0   0      0
11  69456  66837    5   2      1
```

*How it works:*

The function `ifelse` checks whether `id1` and `id2` are identical. If this is the case, the  value `2` is assigned to corresponding entries in `cat`. If they are not identical, the result of `qtty > 0` is assigned. The latter returns a logical vector of boolean (`FALSE` and `TRUE`) values which are cast to integers (`0` and `1`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Great, the solution just writing one line.